# Intent key naming convention

Tags: android

simple question about intent action naming convention: I have a new service that handles an intent. It checks the intent for key com.foo.bar.ServiceName.MANAGER_NAME I have extra arguments I want to pass, should the key be com.foo.bar.ServiceName.MANAGER_NAME.MANAGER_ARGUMENT or just com.foo.bar.ServiceName.MANAGER_ARGUMENT?

Comment: duplicate, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4433790/naming-convention-for-passing-data-through-extras-in-android

Answer (score 4, accepted):

generally these constants will be declared directly in the Service, and will therefore be named like your latter option -- com.foo.bar.ServiceName.MANAGER_ARGUMENT